# Is this true :${(a+ib)}^{(k+ij)}=0$ iff $0<a=k<1$ and $b<j$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, roots, transcendental-numbers

let $z=a+ib ,s=k+ij$ are two complex numbers and let $f(z,s)$ be a complex

function defined as follow :$$f(z,s)=z^s={(a+ib)}^{(k+ij)}$$ and $a,b,j, k$ 
are non -nul real numbers .

.After some calculations in wolfram alpha which i performed I got this:

$f(z,s)$ approach to zero iff $0<a=k<1$ and $b<j$ .

**My question here:** Is "$f(z,s)=0$ iff $0<a=k<1$ and $b<j$"really a true   claim ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Sorry, but that "definition" does not define anything. Exponentiation can be defined as a single-valued function on complex numbers, in which cas you lose a lot of expected properties of exponentiation, or it can be defined as a multi-valued function, retaining some of the usual properties of exponentiation but losing single values.  What doe you mean "approaches zero"?

Comment: Essentially, you need to be much more specific. Using the usual definition, $f(s,z)$ is never zero(but is undefined when $z=0$.

Comment: pleas check this result in WA  :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285%2B2i%29^%285%2B18i%29&dataset=&equal=Submit

Comment: I meant by approches zeros mean  f(z,s) almost equal 0

Comment: Wolfram is not mathematics, it is computation. If you want to know why Wolfram returns various values, that's ran entirely different question.

Comment: yes, and i said z is never 0 beacause ,a,b,k, j are non nul real numbers

Comment: You ask: "Is $f(z,s)=0$ iff ...a true claim." Given that $f(z,s)$ is never zero when defined, that question is meaningless. Again, you have to be clear what you mean by your question.

Comment: If you mean "approaches $0$", don't write "$= 0$".  You'll just confuse us.

Comment: But  "$f(z,s)$ approaches $0$" is a statement about a limit.  A limit as what goes to what?